# Name server IP is changing automatically during the day

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, nameserver, dns-hosting

I have 2 ns records (NS1 and NS2) that point to server1 (IP 1.1.1.1) 
I am currently migrating server1 and i have changed my NS2 record to point to server2 (IP:2.2.2.2). 
So now i have NS1 pointing to server1 and NS2 pointing to server2

My problem is that if i ping my NS2 during the day the ping returns an IP of 2.2.2.2 which is how it should be. Weird enough if i ping NS2 at night it will return the IP of 1.1.1.1

how could that happen? it's been almost 3 days that i have changed the IP of NS2

Sorry for the confusion and to make things clearer. I am not looking for a solution here. I just wanted to know if anyone has experienced such a thing before.
Apparently our DNS server had a CPU problem and it went down several times (blue screen) which led the server to provide the old IP addresses after the reboot. so that's why when i ping it in the morning it provides the right (new) IP and after the reboot it provides the old one. The old server is now totally down and i am looking to change the name server to some hosted service online. Can anyone suggest a good online DNS service!
Thank you

Comment: Please provide the actual domains and host names in question.

Comment: Slightly more pointedly than EEAA above: Any answer to this question in its current form can only be guesswork. If you provide the actual domain name and IP addresses involved, then we can look and likely determine what is *actually* wrong with your setup, and provide suggestions on how to fix that. So please, [edit] your question to give the real details. (And next time you obfuscate, please do so using the [names and networks specifically reserved for such purposes](https://michael.kjorling.se/computers/internet-reservations/examples-and-documentation).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question does not have enough details but most likely the domain uses multiple nameservers and there may be a Zone transfer problem between them so one of the nameservers is providing the old IP.

It would not really be a day/night issue but rather random and of course DNS caches on your PC, DNS server, etc. make it look like it does not change, the change would only be noticeable after the TTL expires and one of the authoritative DNS servers get queries...

Comment: actually this is what i wanted to hear at the beginning but apparently what happened is that after i changed the NS records the server went down (blue screen most probably) and rebooted. it did not save the records properly. so after the reboot the dns server was giving the old IP addresses instead